# XSL Apply template with OR

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to apply a template but only for the first match. Suppose I have a xml like:

```
<cd>
    <title>Red</title>
    <artist>The Communards</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>London</company>
    <price>7.80</price>
    <year>1987</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <artist>Joe Cocker</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>EMI</company>
    <price>8.20</price>
    <year>1987</year>
</cd>
```

Note that the second CD has no title node.
and xsl:

```
<xsl:template match="title">
  Title: <xsl:value-of select="."/><br/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="artist">
  Artist: <xsl:value-of select="."/><br/>
</xsl:template>
```

If there is a node title I want to apply that template and otherwise I want to apply the template for artist. I'm trying something like

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="title | artist"/>
```

But there then it will use both ones, and I only want the first one to be applied. So if there is a title, use that one, otherwise use the artist. Can this be done in such a way or only by using `<xsl:choose>`?

Comment: `match="artist[not(preceding-sibling::title or following-sibling::title)]"`?

Comment: @biziclop That would mean the XML is always in the same order, which (in my case) it isn't. Or at least I can't depend on it.

Comment: No, it would mean that the artist template would only match if it had no (preceding or following) sibling called `title`. It's equivalent to `artist[not(../title)]`, but demonstrates the idea a bit better.

Comment: @biziclop You are right, sorry. I thought it had to be a directly before or after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If there is a node title I want to apply that template and otherwise I
>   want to apply the template for artist.

Write a template matching `title`

```
<xsl:template match="title">
```

and the other one `artist`, given that its parent node does not have a child `title` element.

```
<xsl:template match="artist[not(../title)]">
```

Assuming correct input (the XML you show is not well-formed because there is no single document element), you can apply the stylesheet below.

**Stylesheet**

If your stylesheet outputs text, it is advisable to put it inside `xsl:text` elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="title">
      <xsl:text>Title: </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="artist[not(../title)]">
        <xsl:text>Artist: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Output**

```
Title: Red
Artist: Joe Cocker
```

Comment: perfect! I use this <xsl:apply-templates select="(title | artist[not(../title)])"/>

Comment: @Nin You could, but then you also have to change the content of this template because you then need to decide inside the template whether "Title: " or "Artist: " should be output.

Comment: Which should be dead simple, using `<text><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></text>`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Exactly, and uppercasing the first letter.

Comment: It's just an example xml, I'm not really working on a CD catalog project ;)

Comment: Note that `<xsl:apply-templates select="(a | b)"/> does not preclude separate templates for the two.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="(title | artist)[1]"/>
```

Note the use of `select` instead of `match`. The `xsl:apply-templates` element has no `match` attribute.